# webpack-dev-server vs nodemon

Tags: webpack-dev-server, nodemon

Are there any (dis)advantages in using webpack-dev-server over nodemon.  Does anybody have real experience with it? I am used to `nodemone` and I know it can be used in production too. Whereas `webpack-dev-server` is suitable for dev only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nodemon is a deamon process whic looks only for file changes and restarts node application in case of change. If the any error occurs then it is not able to restart in such cases. Failure occurs

```
EADDRUSE Address is already in use.
```

```
//Nodemon fails to restart.
```

It is very basic and cannot bundle your modules and files used in the project.

Webpack is an advanced tool. It helps you to bundle all your dependencies and library files into one single file and also checks for syntax and other errors. It creates the file on the fly.

When using React, it is an indispensible tool since it allows hot module replacement. It also does the same for Angular 2.

If you require examples on How to use webpack, I can  provide you with many examples.

Comment: Thank you Sumit.  If you want you can provide some examples. I've chosen nodemon some while ago. It could be useful for someone.